# How push back view when click on row of table view?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I want to set an event that when we select any row then open a new view similarly when user click on row then user go back to first view. For example user have button in main view  when click on that button then open a table view. When user click on any row then navigation controller push view to back to main view not in forward view. How implement this event in my project?

Comment: Sorry to be so blunt, but try reading Apple's documentation, or following a tutorial next time, the question asked here is trivial, and there's plenty of information about UITableViews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In table view delegate `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` use -

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
}
```